# Add A Main Navigation Menu Near Website Logo

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been working on my site: [www.zdrctry.com](http://www.zdrctry.com).

I have a couple questions about the **top navigation bar** (containing Home, Contact Us, Cart, My Account):

1. How could I move the navigation bar down to the same level as the "Directory Theme" logo. It is similar to the Red Header of website: [www.premiumpress.com](http://www.premiumpress.com).
2. I'd also like to know how to align the navigation links to the right side of the page.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using css from the www.premiumpress.com?
Also provide illustration on align to the right side?

Answer (score 0):

Put your navigation bar inside a div and make the div's width 100%. Now for the CSS for your nav bar element, put text-align: right.
To move the bar down, use absolute positioning and specify how far from the top of the page you want it.